# Not able to assign new dataset to ng4 chart

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng4-charts

I am using ng4 charts. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-charts

I am declaring dataset as an empty array, however after assigning new data to the variable, chart is not getting refreshed.

My source code is as below

Model

TimesheetLogged.ts

```
export interface TimesheetLogged {
ProjectId: string,   
MondayHours: number,
TuesdayHours: number,
WednesdayHours: number,
ThursdayHours: number,
FridayHours: number,
SaturdayHours: number,
SundayHours: number
```

}

Project.ts

```
import { TimesheetLogged } from "./TimesheetLogged";

export interface Project {
    ProjectId: number;  
    TimeLoggedHours: TimesheetLogged[];   
}
```

Piece of code from Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'timelog',
    templateUrl: '/app/Component/timelog.html'
})

export class TimeLogComponent implements OnInit {
 .
 .
 .
 .

public barChartLabels = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
public barChartType = 'bar';
public barChartLegend = true;
public barChartData = [
    { data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }
];
public Projects: Project[];
//Get projects data from database and subscribe to Projects object  Successfully

let chartData: Array<number> = [];
let mon:number= 0;
let tue:number= 0;
let wed:number= 0;
let thu:number= 0;
let fri:number= 0;
let sat:number= 0;
let sun:number= 0;

this.Projects.forEach(empHours => {
    empHours.TimeLoggedHours.forEach(hours => {
            mon += hours.MondayHours;
            tue += hours.TuesdayHours;
            wed += hours.WednesdayHours;
            thu += hours.ThursdayHours;
            fri += hours.FridayHours;
            sat += hours.SaturdayHours;
            sun += hours.SundayHours;
    });            
});
chartData.push(mon);
chartData.push(tue);
chartData.push(wed);
chartData.push(thu);
chartData.push(fri);
chartData.push(sat);
chartData.push(sun); 


 this.barChartData[0].data = chartData;
.
.   
.

}//End of Component
```

html

```
 <div class="row">
    <canvas baseChart
            [datasets]="barChartData"
            [labels]="barChartLabels"
            [options]="barChartOptions"
            [legend]="barChartLegend"
            [chartType]="barChartType"></canvas>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you tell me what is a change detection setting in the component that you are talking about?

Comment: Even if I have assigned new data to dataset (this.barChartData[0].data = chartData;) My graph is not getting refreshed.

Comment: and if you and correct data initially the chart is displaying properly? Also can you include the component annotation? `@Component({ .... })` i want to see if you are using the default change detection.

Comment: Updated the code. Please verify